# Problema con mysqli. Instruccion insert php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Hola! Estoy teniendo un error al ejecutar el codigo y mandar el dato por POST.
He intentado muchas cosas pero aún no funciona.**

El problema es que cuando escribo el número y le doy a enviar me da el mensaje de error automáticamente y no se registra en la base de datos. No entiendo por qué.

(he censurado la ip y la contraseña de la bdd)

El código:

```
<?
$nombre_cli = $_GET["nombre"]; 
$manzana = $_GET["mnz"];
$lote = $_GET["lt"];
$mesultpago = $_GET["multpg"];
$importe = $_GET["impo"];
$saldoultmes = $_GET["sld"];
$ultcuota = $_GET["cuo"];
$ultcuotade = $_GET["cuode"];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Agregar Cuota | Inmobiliaria </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <p>Agregar Cuotas</p>
            <input type="number" name="cuotasag">
            <input type="submit" name="env">
        </form>
        <? if (isset($_POST["env"])) {
            $cuotasaingresar = $_POST["cuotasag"];
            $cuotasyaingresadas = 0;
            
                $cuotainsfinal = $ultcuota++;
                if ($mesultpago == "Enero") {
                $mespago_ingresar = "Febrero";
                } else {
                if ($mesultpago == "Febrero") {
                    $mespago_ingresar = "Marzo";
                } else {
                    if ($mesultpago == "Marzo") {
                    $mespago_ingresar = "Abril";
                    } else {
                        if ($mesultpago == "Abril") {
                        $mespago_ingresar = "Mayo";
                        } else {
                            if ($mesultpago == "Mayo") {
                            $mespago_ingresar = "Junio";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $IP = "---- censurado ----";
            $Usu = "pabgypco_donfer";
            $Contra = "---- censurado ----";
            $conexion = mysqli_connect($IP, $Usu, $Contra, "---- censurado ----");
                $fechapago_ingresar = date(t) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . date(Y);
                $importeparaconv = $importe;
                $saldo_ingresar = $saldoultmes - $importeparaconv;
                $sqlinsertarcuota = "INSERT INTO PagosDeClientes (Manzana, Lote) VALUES ($manzana, $lote)";
                if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlinsertarcuota)) {
                    echo "Cuotas ingresadas";
                } else { 
                echo "Error!!!";
                mysqli_error($conexion);
                }
            }
          ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Así sería la página normal:
[image: pag]

Pero cuando le doy a enviar, me aparece el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!!

**ACTUALIZACIÓN -------**

Lo he resuelto. El problema era que el usuario no tenía permisos para hacer el comando INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN - - - - - - -**

Lo he resuelto. El problema era que el usuario no tenía permisos para hacer el comando INSERT